# Writing java docs - showing an output example

Tags: java, documentation

I'm asking myself how to show an example of an output in java docs. 
See here...

```
/**
 * Returns the app's version-info (e.g.: "App 1.2").
 */
public static String getAppVersionInfo() {
    return getAppName() + " " + getVersionName();
}
```

How to express the 'e.g.' in a convenient way?

Comment: Define _proper way_.

Comment: Javadoc supports HTML and has special markup to link to existing classes. There's a bunch of possibilities here.

Comment: A common notation?^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Javadoc doesn't have a special tag for example values.

The closest thing to what you are describing that I remember encountering would be examples of hashing algorithms in [`MessageDigest#getAlgorithm()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#getAlgorithm--). In that case the authors simply say

> ... The name should be a standard Java Security name (such as "SHA", "MD5", and so on). ...

There is also the [Javadoc HowTo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html), which specifically discourages using "e.g.":

> **Avoid Latin**
>
> use "also known as" instead of "aka", use "that is" or "to be specific" instead of "i.e.", use "for example" instead of "e.g.", and use "in other words" or "namely" instead of "viz."

Other than that, I'm not aware of any rules or best practices applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thanks cinnam, the "such as"-expression looks neat to me.